# Accessing an object from ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A lot of questions have bees asked about accessing objects but I couldn't find one that answers my problem.

I have a dynamically created object like this :

```
{
    id: "ISO 19115:MD_Metadata:identificationInfo:extent:temporalElement:extent",
    value: "ISO   19115:MD_Metadata:identificationInfo:extent:temporalElement:extent:endPosition",
    begin: "ISO 19115:MD_Metadata:identificationInfo:extent:temporalElement:extent",
    ...
}
```

What I'd like to do is display in ng-options (angularJS) the couples (id - ISO 19115:MD... , value - ISO 19115:MD...) for the second parameter is the path through the first.

So I was wondering if something like that could work:

```
 <select ng-model='selectedtype' ng-options="(item[0] + item[1]) for item in types">
        <option value="">select type</option> 
 </select>
```

note that my object is in `$scope.types`.

This does not work so is there a solution like a designated keyword for accessing name:value couple.

I'm aware that this is quite bad designing for an object and that I should try something like this :

```
{
 [
    {
        'name': 'id',
        'value':'ISO 19115 ...',
    },
    ....
 ]
}
```

But I'd appreciate another solution if possible.

Comment: Just as a side note, it's definitely *not* "better design" to make an array of objects that have only "name" and "value" keys. Objects are specifically name-value pairs.

Comment: Isn't it `item.id` and `item.value` instead of `item[0]` and `item[1]`?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, you want to display value and store id in your select model. Is that what you are aiming for? if so `ng-options="item.id as item.value for item in types"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following format in order to access an objects key-value pair:

```
ng-options="key as key+': '+value for (key, value) in types"
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/kuLhC/)**.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-options` supports string concatenations. So you can easily use something like,

`ng-options="'id-'+item.id+', value-'+item.value for item in types"`

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/XHXKnNJOaDEAITtkI3HC?p=preview

Comment: If you read the question the OP is storing the name and value in separate indexes. The code you provided would not work because of this.

Comment: drew_w is right but  your answer helped me for another problem so thanks!